# Programmatically activate a node in Infragistics XamDataTree

Tags: tree, infragistics

I'm using Infragistics NetAdvantage for Win Client 2010 Vol. 3.

I made a WPF User Control that shows some nested items using a XamDataTree control.
Tree nodes are loaded from a binded Observable item collection:

```
            MenuNode menuTree = getMenuTree(true);
            ObservableCollection<MenuNode> menuNodes = menuTree.children;
            this.treeFP.ItemsSource = menuNodes;
```

I couldn't find a suitable tree method that activates a node based on certain property (eg. a key?). So I created a method that loops through the whole tree, until it finds the correct node to activate:

```
            void selectNode(XamDataTreeNodesCollection nodes, string nodeKey)
```

I then called this method in this way:

```
            selectNode(theTree.Nodes, "KEYTOSELECT");
```

It turned out that theTree.Nodes collection is empty! Why?
Probably because items source is binded? If this behaviour is correct (?), is there another way to activate a single node?

Comment: You should try posting this on the forum for the XamDataTree: http://forums.infragistics.com/forums/478.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a problem of asynchronous loading of tree nodes. Method 'selectNode' must be called from tree_Loaded event handler and it works.

Here's a more detailed answer: http://forums.infragistics.com/forums/t/56486.aspx.